# Error in turning ON the LED using UART in PIC32

Tags: led, pic, c, uart

I have a `PIC32 starter Kit` & `IO Expansion Board`. `PIC32 Starter Kit` has 3 LEDs on baord `LED1 LED2 LED3` . I have made a uart program such that if someone presses 1 on the keyboard, this 1 will be send serially to PIC32 and `LED1` will be ON and if someone presses 4, `LED1` will be OFF. In the same way, 2 & 5 will `turn ON & OFF` `LED2` & 3 & 6 for `LED3`. Program is running fine and `LED1 & LED3` are responding properly but `LED2` is always turn ON whether I press the 2 or not. I dont know why is this happening with this LED2. Is there anything which I am missing. I know LEDs are working but I dont know what is happening in this case. Does anyone have any idea about this thing. Please help.

CODE:

```
#include <plib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma config FNOSC = PRIPLL, POSCMOD = HS, FPLLMUL = MUL_18, FPLLIDIV = DIV_2, FPBDIV = DIV_2, FPLLODIV = DIV_1
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF

#define SYSTEM_FREQUENCY        72000000L
#define BAUDRATE                57600

int main()
{
    int pbFreq;
    TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0; //output
    TRISDbits.TRISD1 = 0; //output
    TRISDbits.TRISD2 = 0; //output

    char RxBuffer[5];

    pbFreq=SYSTEMConfigPerformance(SYSTEM_FREQUENCY);
    OpenUART2( UART_EN | UART_NO_PAR_8BIT | UART_1STOPBIT, UART_RX_ENABLE | UART_TX_ENABLE, (pbFreq/16/BAUDRATE)-1);

while(1)
    {

        if((U2STAbits.URXDA)!=0)
        {
            getsUART2(5,RxBuffer , 123);

            U2STAbits.URXDA = 0;
            U2STAbits.OERR = 0; 


        }


        if(RxBuffer[0] == '1')
        {
            PORTDbits.RD0 = 1;
            putsUART2(">>LED: 1 ON");

           memset(RxBuffer,0,5*sizeof(char));
    }
    else if(RxBuffer[0] == '4')
    {
        PORTDbits.RD0 = 0;
        putsUART2(">>LED: 1 OFF");

        memset(RxBuffer,0,5*sizeof(char));
    }


    if(RxBuffer[0] == '2')
    {
        PORTDbits.RD1 = 1;
        putsUART2(">>LED: 2 ON");
        memset(RxBuffer,0,5*sizeof(char));
    }
    else if(RxBuffer[0] == '5')
    {
        PORTDbits.RD0 = 0;
        putsUART2(">>LED: 2 OFF");
        memset(RxBuffer,0,5*sizeof(char));
    }

    if(RxBuffer[0] == '3')
    {
        PORTDbits.RD2 = 1;
        putsUART2(">>LED: 3 ON");
        memset(RxBuffer,0,5*sizeof(char));
    }
    else if(RxBuffer[0] == '6')
    {
        PORTDbits.RD2 = 0;
        putsUART2(">>LED: 3 OFF");
        memset(RxBuffer,0,5*sizeof(char));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your code.

In this section:

```
 else if(RxBuffer[0] == '5')
    {
        PORTDbits.RD0 = 0;
        putsUART2(">>LED: 2 OFF");
        memset(RxBuffer,0,5*sizeof(char));
    }
```

You should be setting .RD1 to zero instead of .RD0.